# JQuery / Javascript selector loop through array of elements with toggle() or add/removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have:

```
<button id="1"> Button 1 </button>
<span id="s1"> Span 1 </span>

<button id="2"> Button 2 </button>
<span id="s2"> Span 2 </span>

<button id="3"> Button 3 </button>
<span id="s3"> Span 3 </span>
```

What I need is:

-When click button 1, span 1 shows and when click again it disappears and shows the button 1.
-When click button 2, span 2 shows and when click again it disappears and shows the button 2.
-When click button 3, span 3 shows and when click again it disappears and shows the button 3.

I currently have a loop creating the html, assigning ids in an array and set to a class  (.off) with display: none by default. For example:

```
$.(body).append( '<button id="'+[i]+'">Button'+[i]+'</button>
                  <span id="'+[i]+'" class="off">'
```

But I am having trouble selecting one by one. I get errors like, either only the first element works, or I click on 1 button and shows all the spans at the same time. My code:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < id.length; j++ ){
    $('button' ).on("click", function(e) {
        $('span' ).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        $(this).on("click", function(e) {
             $('span').removeClass('on').addClass('off');             
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for good format of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not need to use a loop

```
$(document).on("click", 'button', function(e) {
    $(this).next('span' ).toggleClass('off on');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fMtma/)

Comment: Hey, yesterday it worked but today I added fresh Json with same format but new data and it broke toggleClass strangely. Add or RemoveClass still work but toggleClass broke. Any ideas?

Comment: @rebHelium whether your generated html has changed?

Comment: Not at all. Is very strange. I did console.log after every single variable and all the elements are the same compared side by side with both JSONs. One thing I notice is that when I use toggleClass() and press the button, in the developers tool it shows how it attempts to target the class but it does not succeed in re-writing it. Strange. I can use add / remove class and it works but then I am not succeeding in hiding the span again when I click the button for the second time.

Comment: @rebHelium are you sure the click handler is getting called... also it might be that some other script is interfering with this script... can you add a `console.log()` stmt in the handler function and see what is happening

Comment: Hi Arun. Thank you. Will do tomorrow morning and let you know.